# How to properly format and image a Win10 USB boot media from Linux?

Tags: linux, windows-10, partitioning

I recently built a custom desktop, and am severely struggling to get Windows10 to install (Mint worked the first try). I've searched forums (including Microsoft), and the frequent answer is that the boot image may be corrupted or to use a USB < 3.0 port. I have re-downloaded the image multiple times, so I am pretty sure it's not the former, and unfortunately my desktop only had USB 3.0 and no optical drive.

Anyways, to the problem. It seems that Windows requires that the USB media be formatted as either FAT32 or NTFS (varying answers), and that it must be GPT. In mint, Formatting the drive using the GUI doesn't seem to give the option of GPT. When I try to install windows, it complains of missing drivers after the first screen. Entering the DOS prompt and checking `diskpart` confirms that there is no asterisk by the USB disk. I follow forum instructions to run clean and convert the media to gpt.

When I go back into Mint to re-burn the .iso, when using the "Make bootable USB stick" menu option, it always converts the drive to a UDF format.

Here is the relevant error message I get in the installer:

> A media driver your computer needs is missing. This could be a DVD, USB, or Hard disk driver

Can anyone please confirm how one would properly make this USB media from *within Linux*?

I have tried the following:

- Tried a USB 1.0 stick, every USB port (MoBo and Headers)
- Tried creating Media using UnNetbootin and Rufus (via Wine)
- Tried simply mounting the image and copying the contents
- Fiddled with about every BIOS setting (deleting default boot keys, Enabling CSM mode, Disabling Secure Boot, and toggling media support between Legacy and UEFI)

Other details that might be contributing:

- I have an Asus X5740 motherboard with only USB 3.0 ports
- I am trying to install on an M.2 SSD. Maybe Win10 doesn't have driver support for it?

Apologies if this doesn't belong on this forum, but I figured I'd start on the linux end first to see if I can rule out that I'm simply not creating the media correctly. Any help on this would make my week!

Answer (score 4):

After some trial and error, I found a [process](https://www.linuxbabe.com/ubuntu/easily-create-windows-10-bootable-usb-ubuntu) that worked:

- Download and install gparted (`sudo apt-get install gparted`)
- Use it to create a GPT partition table on the USB drive
- Format it as NTFS (FAT32 will cause an error due to max file size)
- Right click the .iso file, and select the "Open with Image Mounter". This will mount the image like a drive. **Don't** use the "create bootable USB drive" option, Rufush, Unetbootin, etc.
- Copy-paste the contents to the USB drive. This will take ~5-10 minutes with USB 3.0
- In BIOS settings, **disable** CSM to auto
- Make sure Secure Boot is disabled
- Move the drive up in boot priority or manually boot from it

Comment: in my case was not enough. I've run `ms-sys -z /dev/sdX`, ms-sys -7 /dev/sdX and `ms-sys -n /dev/sdX1`, although I am not sure if the last one is really needed. My thumb drive was slow, so, at boot tima, I had blinking cursor ... Windows logo ... blinking cursor ... Windows logo ... install/rescue menus...

Comment: CSM seems to be an obstacle.